# What is the most fast way to show "secure" images with Laravel and Amazon s3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

In my Laravel application I have a gallery for logged-in users with Amazon S3.

Now I download EVERY thumbnail and image in this way:

```
public function download($file_url){ // is safe, but slow...
    $mime = \Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getMimetype($file_url);
    $size = \Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getSize($file_url);

     $response =  [
         'Content-Type' => $mime,
         'Content-Length' => $size,
         'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
         'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename={$file_name}",
         'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
    ];

    return \Response::make(\Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_url), 200, $response);
}
```

This is safe (because I have a router with `middleware('auth')`, but is very server-intensive and slow.

Is it possible to download a file directly from Amazon:

- only for (in my Laravel)-loggedin users (mayby with a temporery download link)?
- **OR** only with a secure unique link?

Comment: You can share objects using pre-signed URLs. Your server would create a signed URL for a given object and user session, then share that URL, allowing a web page to retrieve the object directly from S3. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use temporary URLs:

```php
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
    'file.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

First param is the path on S3, second param is how long you want the URL to work for. Set this to a low value if you only want the URL to work for a single page load.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem (under Temporary URLs)